How can one determine whether using a particular extension in Haskell is a good idea?
I'm continuously asking myself whether there is a way to implement this or that thing in Haskell. Sometimes, I succeed in figuring out a solution, and it's not rare for such a solution to require a language extension. Should I opt for it without a second thought, given it provides a necessary feature, or may using a particular language extension be undesirable? Is there a conventional way to determine this for an extension of interest?

Most extensions actually are just rewrites of the original code. For example OverloadedStrings rewrites every string literal to fromString ....

Typically if the extension does not result in Undeciable..., the compiler can not get stuck in an infinite loop. It can sometimes generalize the type system, which makes it less convenient to define functions. So perhaps the smallest subset of things you need for convenience.

See https://wiki.haskell.org/index.php?title=Use_of_language_extensions

In my eye, most extensions are OK, and I wish many were on by default. Undecidable... allow you to write code that will make the type checker loop forever, but it does not cause real harm otherwise. The only ones that I recommend to avoid as much as possible are OverlappingInstances and IncoherentInstances, since they make instance selection quite fragile. By contrast, AllowAmbiguousTypes is the most harmless of them all (IMO), despite its scary name.

@chi: probably some will be enabled by default if they publish a new Haskell standard :) since that essentially happened with Haskell'10 vs Haskell'98: https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_2010

Also, recent GHCs offer conservative bundles of extensions through the language editions GHC2021 and GHC2024. Alexis King's An opinionated guide to Haskell in 2018 includes a good rundown of extensions, even if a few things have evolved since (for instance, the addition of the aforementioned language editions).

Almost every extension is fine to enable without a second thought. These are the exceptions:

AllowAmbiguousTypes - GHC will often suggest this when it won't actually resolve your problem, but rather just push the error elsewhere. If you actually want to create something that can't be used without a type application, then this is fine to enable, though.
DatatypeContexts - put the constraints on all of the functions that will use the types instead
ImplicitParams - can lead to surprising incoherence
IncoherentInstances - put {-# INCOHERENT #-} on individual instances instead, so that you don't accidentally write incoherent instances you don't mean to
NPlusKPatterns - write, e.g., fac n = n * fac (n-1) instead of fac (n+1) = (n+1) * fac n
OverlappingInstances - put {-# OVERLAPPING #-}, {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}, or {-# OVERLAPS #-} on individual instances instead, so that you don't accidentally write overlapping instances you don't mean to


Worth noting that DatatypeContexts and NPlusKPatterns are sort of reverse extensions. They control features that were originally standard parts of the language, but which have been commonly enough regarded as misfeatures that they were turned into extensions so that they could be disabled.

Today, start with GHC2021.
It used to be that pretty basic functionality was not there without defining a set of language extensions, but with with recent compilers, the default GHC2021 has most if not all of those.
For any additional extensions just go and read their descriptions to discover whether you need them. Though, IncoherentInstances I don't think you'd ever need, and even "if you do" there are probably better encodings of your domain than the one you are currently trying to implement.
